# ASMX and cs reference

Tags: c#, asmx

I am new in .Net and I am dancing with the ugliest since I had to create an old asmx file without VisualStudio, basically editing the file and test in the IIS.

My question is how I can get a reference to a cs files (that are related between them, same namespace) into the asmx file. 
I was able to add one file with the following... but I get errors when I add various files and they are related each other, basically the errors is that they cannot see each other

```
<%@ Assembly Src="class1.cs" %>
<%@ Assembly Src="class2.cs" %>
```

Comment: I think you can have only one code-behind file for an asmx file,

Comment: If we put “new in .NET”, "an old asmx", and "without Visual Studio" together, this question itself is against all the good will of modern .NET movement. Why do you want to learn .NET the hardest way in 2018, when there are tons of better ones ahead?

Comment: it's a job task, old technology and deprecated plc privative devices, I can use Visual Studio Express 2015(that's why I want to use some code in cs, at least to have something), but it does not support old ASMX. if it was my election I won't use .net at all.